# Retrieving JSON data via HTTP GET using Spring Android Framework

Tags: android

I am using spring android framework for retrieving json data via Http GET. I am getting following exception for the same :

**- Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of com.springandroidjsondemo.beans.LoginBean[] out of START_OBJECT token**

**The bean (LoginBean) is Following**

```
    package com.springandroidjsondemo.beans;

public class LoginBean {



    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

The android code is following :

```
  HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application", "json")));

HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
// Create a new RestTemplate instance
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
// Add the Jackson message converters
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

// Make the HTTP GET request, marshaling the response from JSON to an array of Events
ResponseEntity<LoginBean[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,LoginBean[].class); // getting exception here

LoginBean[] loginBean = responseEntity.getBody();
String status = loginBean[0].getStatus();
```

The json response from the server is following :

```
{"emp-data":[{"status":"true"}]}
```

I am not sure if any annotations are required for Jackson Marshalling

Please suggest the solution

Thanks!

Comment: You can use normal JSON parsing in android. http://sayemsiam.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/communication-between-php-and-android/#more-8

Comment: Thanks for the response !!Yes that can be used and that I have done.. But I want to implement this using spring android framework. I followed the steps given on springsource.com but I am unable to implement that...

Answer (score 0):

this is a Jackson deserialization issue. if you compare the JSON response with your LoginBean, the array of statuses is contained within the element "emp-data". However, your RestTemplate request is expecting JSON which looks like the following.

```
[{"status":"true"},{"status":"false"}]
```

You have a couple options. You can create a wrapper object around LoginBean. Or you can try annotating the LoginBean like the following:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "emp-data")
public class LoginBean {

    ...
}
```

In order for this to work, you probably need to configure the Jackson ObjactMapper.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
jackson.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(jackson);
```